# How to import every model, function and other things in django project?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am working on a Django project.
I currently import functions, models like:

```
from project.abc.models import *
from project.cba.models import *
from project.abc.views import *
from project.cba.views import *
```

Is there any syntax which can enable me to write just the name of project and it may return every model, functions and etc from every application like:

```
from project.models import *
from project.views import *
from project.urls import *
```

I am using Django1.3, and I know that it is not a good practice to import `*` of anything, but this is my need at the moment. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it is not a good idea but if you want you can create a file models.py in your project root directory and write there:

```
from project.abc.models import *
from project.cba.models import *
```

after that you can import your models like:

```
from project.models import SomeModel
```

And you also can create views.py etc.

Comment: @Andery Kaygorodov: You are absolutely right! but I am just fed up writing the same line in every file, this really violates the rules of `OOP`, btw thanks for the solution

Comment: In my projects I don't use imports like project.someapp.models (or views, urls etc.), I use someapp.models or someapp.views i.e. without  project.

Comment: But I have described in my question that in every file I need to import every of the models or functions leaving just one or two some times. That is why I decided to have an approach like this.